# Meaning of Going to be a while

Tags: usage

A friend of mine, who is a native speaker of US English, used this expression while speaking:

> All the parents are busy right now. They are discussing a lot of stuff. They are clearly ***going to be a while***.

What does this expression mean? Is this suggesting that they were going to be late or would take more time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"It is going to be a while" or "it will be a while" both mean that something will take a relatively long amount of time.

Other examples:

> **It is going to be a while** before dinner is ready, so can I get you something to drink?
>
> **The kids are going to be a while** finishing up their schoolwork, so I have time to watch my TV show.